# NullPointerException pointed on int java.io.InputStream.read(byte[], int, int). How to approach a fix?

Tags: android

I've been following a BluetoothChat app tutorial similar to the sample provided by Google. Link to reference here [GoogleSource](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/eclair-passion-release/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChat.java) . I can successfully connect to other phone's Bluetooth when I have not implemented the class that handles the input and output streams. But when I implemented the class (ConnectedThread), it crashes the app with the null pointer exception at the run() method on "*bytes = inputSream.read(buffer)*" inside that class. Any idea on how to approach a fix? Been plaguing me for days. Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**ConnectedThread class**

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothsocket;
    private final InputStream inputStream;
    private final OutputStream outputStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        bluetoothsocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        try {
            tmpIn = bluetoothsocket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = bluetoothsocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ConnectedThrd->Cons", "Socket not created.");
        }
        inputStream = tmpIn;
        outputStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    //App crashes here(?)
                        bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
                        // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                        handler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                                .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("ConnectedThrd->Run", "Connection Lost.", e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }
    }

    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            outputStream.write(buffer);
            handler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ConnectedThread->Write", "Empty write stream.");
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            bluetoothsocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ConnectedThread->Cancel", "Failed to close socket.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about what happens if `getInputStream()` (or `getOutputStream()`) throws an exception in the constructor. You're logging the exception but then just carrying on as if everything's fine. What do you *expect* `run` to do in that case?

Comment: What should i do then? It doesn't even show that the constructor caught an exception in the logcat. @JonSkeet

Comment: Well change the constructor to *not* swallow the exception, to start with. Then you'll need to "do the right thing" (which we can't tell you about, not knowing the context) if the constructor throws an exception when you call it. I'd also encourage you *not* to extend Thread, but to implement Runnable instead.

Comment: Based on the tutorials and on the GoogleResource sample, only a Log is present on the Constructor's catch section.

Comment: You shouldn't be catching the exception *at all* in this case, IMO. But a Stack Overflow comment thread is not the right place to provide a tutorial on exception handling in Java.

Comment: It seems that I found my problem. I still wasn't able to connect to the device. I forgot to add an else statement when using the socket.connect() that's why it falsely showed that device is connected, when in fact, it isn't. It always shows "java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1". Thanks @JonSkeet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the BluetoothSocket was null when I try to send a data to the other device causing this error. Adding a condition to check whether a connection is established helped me handle the error.